# $injector:unpr Unknown provider: cFilterProvider <- cFilter

Tags: angularjs

I am using CodeAcademy to study angular.js, and I am stuck on one excersice. I am getting the aforementioned js error. I googled the error but I haven't find a suitable answer so far.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700italic|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="PizzaPlanetApp">
    <div class="header">
      <h1><span>Pizza</span><span>Planet</span></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Specials for {{ today | date }}</h1>

        <h2>Appetizers</h2>
        <div class="appetizers row" ng-repeat="appetizer in appetizers">
          <div class="item col-md-9">
            <h3 class="name"> {{ appetizer.name }} </h3>
            <p class="description"> {{ appetizer.description }} </p>
          </div>
          <div class="price col-md-3">
            <p class="price"> {{ appetizer.price | c }} </p>
          </div>        
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
  </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("PizzaPlanetApp", []);
```

MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.today = new Date();

  $scope.appetizers = [
    {
      name: 'Caprese',
      description: 'Mozzarella, tomatoes, basil, balsmaic glaze.',
      price: 4.95
    },
    {
      name: 'Mozzarella Sticks',
      description: 'Served with marinara sauce.',
      price: 3.95
    },
    {
        name: "Bruschetta",
      description: "Grilled bread garlic, tomatoes, olive oil.",
      price: 4.95
    }
  ];
}]);
```

When I load index.html in the browser, I still see the template text e.g. `{{ today | date }}` and the following error in JS console:

```
    [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cFilterProvider <- cFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=cFilterProvider%20%3C-%20cFilter
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
    at angular.js:4262
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4409)
    at angular.js:4267
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4409)
    at $get (angular.js:18089)
    at isStateless (angular.js:12954)
    at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (angular.js:13011)
    at angular.js:12965
    at forEach (angular.js:336)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error - similar code I studied in the previous chapter runs fine. Can someone please help me figure out what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo on the following line:

```
<p class="price"> {{ appetizer.price | c }} </p>
```

which should probably be the following to use the currency filter:

```
<p class="price"> {{ appetizer.price | currency }} </p>
```

Angular is looking for filter provider "c" which doesn't exist. But there is a "currency" filter (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, that was it! Thanks a lot!